# How to have multiple dimension X-axis in clustered column [Cognos]

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

In **Cognos** report, I would like to show Month and Week nested together in X-axis .

E.g in April , i have week 16 and week 17. How to show it? When i tried to put the item in 'extra categories', it will not show up in visualization

[image: Preview 1]

[image: design page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognos Analytics comes with multiple charting options,  try doing this nesting in the legacy version of the chart you are using.  Charting Engine selections can be done via the top right of the insert visualization dialog box.